# Nothing is performing after clicking on "Pick from gallery" or "take picture" from camera. Please see my code. Flutter image picker and cropper

Tags: flutter, dart

I am picking image from gallery and taking picture in flutter, i think my code is perfect but nothing is happening after clicking on "Pick from gallery" or "Take a picture" in flutter. I am calling **_showPickOptionsDialog(context)** method  Please see my code for any mistake.

```
      _loadPicker(ImageSource source) async {
        File picked = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
        if (picked != null) {
          _cropImage(picked);
        }
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    
      _cropImage(File picked) async {
        File cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
          androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
            statusBarColor: Colors.red,
            toolbarColor: Colors.red,
            toolbarTitle: "Crop Image",
            toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          sourcePath: picked.path,
          aspectRatioPresets: [
            CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
            CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9,
            CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
          ],
          maxWidth: 800,
        );
        if (cropped != null) {
          setState(() {
            _pickedImage = cropped;
          });
        }
      }
    
      void _showPickOptionsDialog(BuildContext context) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            content: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("Pick from Gallery"),
                  onTap: () {
                    _loadPicker(ImageSource.gallery);
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("Take a picture"),
                  onTap: () {
                    _loadPicker(ImageSource.camera);
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: Check whether you have enabled in necessary permission in respective platforms and handled the runtime permission in Android 6.0 and above !

Comment: Actually i am using immulator in windows,  i applied permission in info.plist file but nothing happen